# Does JOGL marshal any data before it calls into the bound c implementation of openGL?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

Does anyone know if JOGL does any marshalling of data before it calls into the bound c implementation of openGL? From what I understand JOGL doesn't do much more than expose openGL in java.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: I have had a look at the documentation and the APIs it looks to me like its close to a 1 to 1 mapping of the functionality the JOGL actually supports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a look at the documentation and the APIs, it looks to me like its close to a 1 to 1 mapping of the functionality the JOGL actually supports. No marshalling.

Comment: Depends a lot on your definition of marshaling, of course. Transforming between C arrays and Java arrays, for example, takes a certain amount of doing.